# How to extract specific parts of a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the following looking correlation function. [image]
I want to extract only the main peak of the function in a seperate array. The central peak has the form of a gaussian.[image]. I want to seperate the peak with a width arround the peak of approximately four times the FWHM of the gaussian peak. I have the correlation function stored in a numpy array. Any tips/ideas how to approach this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy's `argmax` ([Docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)) function returns the index of the max value of a numpy array. With that value you could then get the values around that index.

Example:

```
m = numpy.argmax(arr)
values = arr[m-width:m+width]
```